# Calculate the distance between two triangular turtles considering the perimeter and not the origin

Tags: python, distance, turtle-graphics, collision, python-turtle

I am trying to be able to identify when one Turtle, as it moves, overlaps with another.

I have tried using the distance function but it takes into account the oridine of the turtle and consequently does not take into account the size of the shape.

```
  att = Turtle()
  dif = Turtle()

  reference = att.heading()
  startpoint = att.position()
  dif_pos = dif.position()    
  Aod = Turtle()
  Aod.penup()
  Aod.color("green")
  Aod.shape("triangle")
  Aod.shapesize(stretch_wid=15,stretch_len=15)    
  Aod.setheading(reference + 180)
  Aod.goto(startpoint)
  Aod.forward(-170)
  print(Aod.distance(dif_pos))
  if Aod.distance(dif_pos) < 50:
      print(Aod.distance(dif_pos))
      print("Is working")`
  else:
      print("No overlap")`
```

This is the portion of the code that controls the overlap of these two turtles.

[Here you can see the red turtle under the top left of the green turtle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/etbCa.jpg)

I tried using the `distance()` function but it considers the origin of the shape and as a result it does not calculate when the edges of the image touch.

Since they are two triangles it is also complicated for me to work using the axis coordinates.